# intellij idea conflicts when add java runtime options

Tags: intellij-idea, java-9

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9`

java 9 does not have java ee packages on the classpath, so I added

`--add-modules java.se.ee`

step by step as in [configure jvm options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties)
However, after reboot IDEA, it prints:

[image: error launching IDEA]

by using 
`echo %JAVA_HOME%`
I could see it points to the correct JDK-9.

And the error would be gone if I deleted `.IntelliJIdea2017.2\config\idea64.exe.vmoptions`
or if I append `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions` to that file.

Comment: Did you define a `JAVA_HOME` as path variable?

Comment: @nullpointer yes. `echo %JAVA_HOME%` it prints the correct JDK-9 path. Somehow, I think intellij idea JVM does not recognize `--add-modules`.

Comment: Where did you add `--add-modules java.se.ee` in intelliJ?

Comment: @nullpointer the first line in that file.

Comment: @Tiina You are running IntelliJ IDEA under the bundled Java 8 and trying to use Java 9 only options which will not work for the obvious reasons. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879.

Comment: @nullpointer I don't think IDEA comes with a jre, I think it uses the one pointed by %JAVA_HOME%. now it is jdk 9, so IDEA should be using JDK 9.

Comment: @Tiina - CrazyCoder is a support lead at IntelliJ and is very often absolutely right. You should pay attention to him/her.

Comment: @CrazyCoder when project uses jdk9, those internal apis kept throwing "classNotFound", so I wish to add `--add-modules java.se.ee`. And now I know the correct place to do so is under `edit configuration`. And that file in the post is to modify intellij idea's running condition which is java8. thx

Comment: @EngineerDollery I took your advice. :)

Comment: You should put that in as an answer, then you'll be able to accept it so that other people can find the solution to this problem too.